# Bash doesn't see the file in the right directory

Tags: bash, perl

I have this bash script;

```
~/build/mosesdecoder/scripts/training/mert-moses.perl \
        ~/factored_translation/dataset/dev.tr ~/factored_translation/dataset/dev.en \
        ~/build/mosesdecoder/bin/moses unfactored/model/moses.ini \
        --mertdir ~/build/mosesdecoder/bin \
        --input-factor-max 4 \
        --decoder-flags="-threads all"
```

When I run it, it gives me this error:

> ./tune-model.sh: line 2:
>   /export/students/sait/build/mosesdecoder/scripts/training/mert-moses.perl:
>   No such file or directory

But I am sure that `mert-moses.pl` is under `/export/students/sait/build/mosesdecoder/scripts/training/` directory, and it exists.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: bad shebang? tried with `perl` prefix? `perl ~/build/mosesdecoder/scripts/training/mert-moses.perl`

Comment: Can't open perl script "/export/students/sait/build/mosesdecoder/scripts/training/mert-moses.perl": No such file or directory

Comment: The file does *not* exists. How many different programs do you need to tell you? `ls -la /path/to/non/existing/file`

Comment: try `ls -F /export/students/sait/build/mosesdecoder/scripts/training`, check if no trailing space for instance.

Comment: I tried. No problem. mert-moses.pl exists.

Comment: `mert-moses.pl` is not the same as `mert-moses.perl`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say in the comments that `mert-moses.pl` exists, but your script looks for `mert-moses.perl`. This is probably the source of your problem.